# ('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))

Tags: node.js, express

I created a express app and having some big issues:

1. My routing is horrendous and can't get my 'Signin' and 'Signup' pages connecting to my home page. Some advice would be really helpful. (I've attached an image of my tree structure)
2. I'm also getting a error - throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))

My app.js

```
    // define dependencies
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var ExpressValidator = require('express-validator');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var multer = require('multer');
//handle file uploads
var upload = multer({des: './uploads'});
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;

// const PORT = 5500; // you can change this if this port number is not available
const router = express.Router();

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

// app.use('/', routes);
// app.use('/users', users);

var app = express();

//view engine setup
app.use('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());


// Handle Sessions
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true
}));

//passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Express Validator middleware
app.use(ExpressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value){
    var namespace = param.split('.'),
    root = namespace.shift(),
    formParam = root;

  while(namespace.length){
    formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
  }
  return {
    param : formParam,
    msg : msg,
    value : value
  };
  }
}));

//express messages middleware
app.use(require('connect-flash')());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});

//catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

//error handlers

//development  error handler
//will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development'){
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

//production erro handler
//no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

// //connect to database
// mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/auth_tuts', { //replace this with you
//   // useMongoClient: true
// }, (err, db) => {
//   if (err) {
//     console.log("Couldn't connect to database");
//   } else {
//     console.log(`Connected To Database`);
//   }
// }
// );


module.exports = app;
```

My user.js

```
var express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// GET home page. 
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.get('/signup', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('signup');
});

module.exports = router;
```

My index.js

```
var express = require('express');[enter image description here][1]
var router = express.Router();

// GET home page. 
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

my package.json file

```
   {
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "College Project",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/KevinKerin/kjs-webdesign.git"
  },
  "author": "Johnathan Munster",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/KevinKerin/kjs-webdesign/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/KevinKerin/kjs-webdesign#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "connect-flash": "*",
    "cookie-parser": "*",
    "debug": "*",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-messages": "*",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "express-validator": "*",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.4.0",
    "mongodb": "*",
    "mongoose": "^5.3.12",
    "morgan": "*",
    "multer": "*",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.8",
    "nodemailer-smtp-transport": "^2.7.4",
    "passport": "*",
    "passport-http": "*",
    "passport-local": "*",
    "serve-favicon": "*",
    "shortid": "^2.2.14"
  }
}
```

File Structure

Comment: why do you have your routes commented in `app.js` ?

Comment: @PranayTripathi is this causing my error? would you know how to solve my error? And help with my routing issues? 

Comment: can you post your package.json as well ? Also initialise your route after your passport session is authenticated else the context will not be used by the middle ware as the app wouldnt be initialised

Comment: hi @PranayTripathi, I've added my package.json file. I'll amend the my code too! Thank you!

Comment: Issue fixed! I had .use instead .set(‘views’, path...)! Working on my routing now

Answer (score 1):

Issue fixed. I had `.use` instead of `.set(‘views’, path...)`

Working on my routing now.